# Erro template ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recebi esse erro enquanto tentava aprender o basico do ruby alguem sabe como resolver?

```
Missing template articles/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "c:/Sites/blog/app/views"
```

Comment: Cola seu código e sua estrutura do projeto, que já resolvemos esse problema!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este erro ocorre quando você tenta chamar uma template(view) que não existe.

Tente criar o método Index colocar na rota e criar a view index.

[]s